# Autoloading doesn't work with variable

Tags: php, variables, namespaces, autoload

I want to autoload a class witha a variable but it doesn't work. Can anybody help me out? 
I have a folder foo with a class A and a subfolder subfoo containing 5 classes (class B, class C, ...)

in class A I want to use the classes and when I do this:

```
$obj = new classB();
```

It works all fine.
When I do this:

```
$name = 'ClassB';
$obj = new $name();
```

It works. And when I move class B from the subfolder to the foo folder, the second script also works.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: So how does the autoloader know that it should be looking for the class file in `foo/subfoo` rather than in `foo`?

Comment: I don't know, I touhgt it would do it automaticly? How does the autoloaders know in the first code snippet to look in foo/subfoo and not in /foo?

And how can I solve this?

Comment: `I don't know, I touhgt it would do it automaticly?` :)

Comment: An autoloader is a piece of code; where did you get your autoloader? What is the code for the autoloader? Are you using namespaces?

Comment: @DainisAbols - I like the term `automagically` myself

Comment: I am building an app with zend framework 2 so I tought that the autoloader from zf2 did all the autoloading
And I am working with namespaces.

Comment: It does, but it still needs to know where to look for the files, it doesn't simply guess... the ZF2 docs should show you the basic directory structure for your files

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I don't think it's how you're instantiating your objects, but more how you are autoloading your classes.

At this point I'm going to assume you know about [php's ability to let you autoload classes](https://www.php.net/autoload). If you don't, then I'd need to know what setup you have (framework? any helper classes?), because that's probably doing the autoloading for you.

It seems like you need to configure your autoload function.

Here's a basic example of what I think your autoload function looks like:

```
function my_autoloader($class) {

    $file = $class . '.class.php'; // E.g. ClassB.class.php

    if(file_exists($file)) {
        require_once($file);
    }

}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

In this case, it's checking the current working directory to see if file `{$class}.class.php` exists.

In the scenario above, you mentioned that you moved your classes into subdirectory `subfoo`.
Therefore, you would need to alter your autoloader function to reflect the new subdirectory, because PHP will not think to look deeper into the directory structure unless you tell it to:

```
    $file = 'subfoo/' . $class . '.class.php'; // Same E.g. will now look for subfoo/ClassB.class.php
```